# H1 within a DIV not working

Tags: html, css

I have a H1 tag with a color set to gray, but on the Home Page, the background color is dark blue, and the grey looks really bad (unreadable).

When I inspect the element, this is what I see:

```
<div class="slide-content">
<header>
<h1>
Some Text
</h1>
```

I tried adding the following rule to the WordPress CSS Editor:

```
  .slide-content header:h1 {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

But the color remains gray.

Can anyone advise what I've done wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: you can address the item like this: `.slide-content header h1 {}`. `:` is reserved for pseudo classes, like `:hover`

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 5):

":" doesn't work with h1, instead do something like `.slide-content header h1 {}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  .slide-content header h1 {
        color: #fff !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be

```
.slide-content header h1 {...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update css**

```
 .slide-content header h1 {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

```css
 .slide-content header h1 {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-content">
<header>
<h1>
Some Text
</h1>
```

**For Testing**  Font Color red

```css
 .slide-content header h1 {
    color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-content">
<header>
<h1>
Some Text
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

H1 tag within the div isn't working:--- It might be possible beacause if u have more than framework or example like if both bootstrap and css are implemented by you...so you should put the bootstrap (link ref) reference link above the css one because it will mark as to run bootstrap first and then css in order.....This worked for me might be useful for you!!